# Why doesn't readLine() work in my Kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, readline

I have this block of code

```
fun main() {
    var input = "1.785 + 9755.44"
    val inputarr = input.split(" ")
    var output = inputarr[0].toDouble() + inputarr[2].toDouble()
    println(output)

    var a: String? = readLine()
    println(a)
}
```

When I run it, it executes up to `print(output)`, but after that it just stops and doesn't even stop the running. I am forced to close the IDE and start again when this happens.

There is no way for me to input anything into `a`.

I thought at first that maybe something was wrong with my setup, but when I tried it on https://play.kotlinlang.org/, I got the different problem.

Instead of showing blank after the `println(output)` part, I got `null` after it.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: How do you provide the input to your program?

Comment: @Cerberus from the tutorial I have been watching, readLine() is supposed to mean input. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5flXf8nuq60&t=752s timeing: 34:58.

Comment: `readLine` is for reading input provided externally, by default via the standard input - https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html.

Comment: @Cerberus so what is the solution?

Comment: Have you tried typing into your IDE (after ensuring that the relevant Run pane is focussed), and pressing Enter? If so, what happens?

Comment: @gidds I tried but there is not input field created. I tried randomly typing after pointing in the area but nothing happened either.

Comment: “but nothing happened” — what did you see, exactly? Was there a flashing cursor in that pane? (If not, then it wasn't focussed.) Did the characters you typed appear in that pane? When you pressed Enter, did the cursor move to the next line?

Comment: @gidds it wasn't focused. Even after pressing enter nothing happened.

Comment: did you type in anything before pressing enter?

Comment: @iamaprogrammer Then focus it! Click in that pane. Then you'll be able to type into it.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html), `readLine()` returns:

> the line read or `null` if the input stream is redirected to a file and the end of file has been reached.

So I guess it depends on your IDE to how to manage the input stream. I tried your code with IntelliJ IDEA and everything was OK.

Try checking your IDE settings to change its behavior or try IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I don't think this is an IDE issue because  I get the same problems on https://play.kotlinlang.org/ and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_kotlin_online.php

Comment: Online editors usually have such stream data issues; they are not built for these kind of programs, their terminals are not implemented for getting data from input stream.
Your code is OK, just execute it in IntelliJ IDEA to see the suitable result.

Comment: I'm having issues with IntelliJ Idea so that's why I used VS Code. The run configuration in IntelliJ is empty and I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Just click on the small green triangle beside your `main()` method and then click Run.

Comment: I did but it just says "setup congiuration"

Comment: Update to last version and create a new Kotlin project. It builds your project using Gradle and everything should be OK.
You will have the best experience with Kotlin programming using IntelliJ IDEA since both of them are developed by JetBrains too. I highly recommend you to try to solve your problem with IntelliJ instead of changing your IDE.